# unwanted nodes from different pools in load-balancer configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

In our google cloud (kubernetes backed) configuration of multiple projects, workloads and service (load-balancers), we specifically configure load-balancers but the configuration seems to change.

We specifically add nodes to our load-balancers, after a while, all of our nodes (from different pools) end up attached to *all* our load balancers.  After they have been magically added back to the load-balancer, we remove them (again), and then sometime later, they're all back.

I realize there is a lot of missing implementation information but was hoping there was some well-known patterns someone thinks we might not be following.  I will try my best to post configuration details.

Comment: Are your load balancers created by Kubernetes using Service with `type LoadBalancer`, or you created them manually?

Comment: The load-balancers were created manually.  Really so we could internally use nginx for some service routing.   However, we are open to changing that or re-creating the load-balancers if required/suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use manually created Load Balancers on Google Cloud with Kubernetes `Services` and `type: NodePort`, it is almost the same thing as you use `type: Load Balancer` for your services, but in the second case, LB is created and managed by Kubernetes, and you don't need to care about it.

Because `Service` with type `NodePort` is binding address on all your nodes, they should be added to the LB as a backend. Check the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service), path "Proxy-mode: iptables". Maybe in your situation, Kubernetes tried to manage it and added all your nodes to LoadBalancers, because they process requests to its services. Actually, I haven’t seen installations where LoadBalancers were created manually and pointed to Kubernetes.

On Google Cloud, I highly recommend you to use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) (based on Google Load Balancer or Nginx) or Services with the `type: Load Balancer`, if you don't need custom routing.

You can implement it like that (for Nginx Ingress):

- Deploy `Nginx Ingress Controller` with Service `type: LoadBalancer`. It will create for you `LoadBalancer` as an entrypoint for all your traffic.
- Deploy your application `Service` with `type: ClusterIP`.
- Create an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) object for your application's `Service` and write all your routing rules there.